# Control Toolbox is empty in Outlook

Tags: outlook

I have searched this site and have been unable to find an answer to my problem. I have Outlook 2013 and I use the developer tab often to create forms and one day my toolbox was just completely empty. I have also scoured the internet and have found others with the same issue but no solution. Can anyone please help!!

Comment: what did you do on the developer tab? Your question is too general and incomplete. Also it does not seem about programming.

Answer (score 0):

You mean that the following Controls is empty of Outlook? You might need to try repairing the Office Installation via the Windows Control Panel. Please see the link:

[Userform toolbox suddenly empty](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/userform-toolbox-suddenly-empty/bf2a1a4b-386c-41b9-966a-f3a893fb4be8)

[image]